# How can I add customer also bought using spree commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, product, related-content

On the [Spree_related_product page](https://github.com/dmasur/spree-related-products) it say that it Gives you a "Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought" Div under every Product. How can I set it up.

Comment: Have you tried this rake after the extension installation and migration `rake spree:extensions:related_products:find_relations`

Comment: That one displays related products that you set up in the admin section. I'm trying to display products that other customers who bought the product also bought.

Comment: After this rake task what is the out put of `Spree::Product.fist.related_products`, Here we assume that some on bought first product.

Comment: Hey I just learned the spree related product [here](https://github.com/dmasur/spree-related-products) the one that add "customer also bought" feature different from the one compatible with spree 3.x [here](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_related_products). I was looking at the noe4j recommendation sytem [here](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/graph-kit-for-ruby-lets-build-a-recommendation-engine-for-a-spree-store) looks promising. thanks for you support.